# Rjson readin large Json error

Tags: r, rjson

I'm trying to read in a 2.4GB json file into R, However, it seems using the routine approach does not work. The error is below. What can I do?

```
Error in paste(readLines(file, warn = FALSE), collapse = "") : 
The result will exceed 2^31-1 BYTE
```

Comment: Try `out <- jsonlite::fromJSON(file, simplifyVector = FALSE)`

Comment: this is the answer, thanks!