# Error: result would exceed 2^31 bytes

Tags: r, out-of-memory, rjson

I am trying to load a JSON file into r using rjson. I get the following error message:

> Error in paste(readLines(file, warn = FALSE), collapse = "") : 
>   result would exceed 2^31-1 bytes

My code is as follows:

```
JsonData <- fromJSON(file= "text.txt", unexpected.escape = "skip" )
```

The file is large (3.47 GB) and from Kaggle, and I assume that it is well formatted.
Is it possible to split a json file, or stream it?

I am using a Mac, Sierra 10.12.6 and the latest versions of r and Rstudio

Comment: [JsonData <- jsonlite::fromJSON(file, simplifyVector = FALSE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696079/rjson-readin-large-json-error#comment64770489_38696079)